# How the omniauth gem create the routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using the [omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) to implement the authentication strategy, but there is one thing I cannot understand: The omniauth would generate some routes to use but I cannot see it by `rake routes`.

For example, the gem [omniauth-saml](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) will generate the `auth/saml` routes, when I visit this path, It will initiate the request phase. However, I cannot find it on the routes list. Therefore, it's hard for me to know which routes have already been created and could be used directly.

Could anyone help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer.

`Omniauth` is a rack based application, so it can handle every HTTP request and do the tasks based on different path. They call the task `phase`.

It includes two mainly phases:

**request phase**: Default path is `"#{path_prefix}/#{name}"`

**callback phase**: Default path is `"#{path_prefix}/#{name}/callback`, customise by `options[:callback_path]`